# How to insert a row in a table3 (idTable1, idTable2) if idTable2 is Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have an issue in SQL.
I have 3 Table

- Table1(id,....,name='name1')
- Table2(id,....,guid='guidTable2')
- Table3(idTable1, idTable2)

I need an sql script to add a row to table3 containing the table1id and table2id, in order to retrieve the auto_increment ids I have the name data for table1 (always unique) and the guid data for table 2 (also always unique).

I thought of something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table3 ( table1id, table2id ) 
VALUES((SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'name1'), (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE guid='guidTable2'))
```

However, in this code I cannot test whether the row returned by :

```
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE guid='guidTable2'
```

is null.

I just want to skip the insert if the idTable2 is null.

I have a lot of insert into to run in the same script and I don't want any errors. If possible, have logs to find out which rows in table 2 don't exist, but that's an improvement.

Any idea ?
Thanks

How to skip an id to insert if it is null

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to check if the row exists in table2 before inserting:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (table1id, table2id)  
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.guid = 'guidTable2'
WHERE t1.name = 'name1'
  AND t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

This will only insert if there is a matching row in table2. To get the rows that didn't match, you can select the rows where t2.id IS NULL:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.guid = 'guidTable2'
WHERE t1.name = 'name1'
  AND t2.id IS NULL
```

So by doing a LEFT JOIN and checking for NULL before the insert, you can skip inserting rows where the table2 row doesn't exist. And by checking for IS NULL after, you can see which ones didn't have a match to log if needed.

Comment: Works very well thanks Ritik ! Any idea for logs ?

Comment: Any idea for logs mean? Please be specific.

Comment: If a row isn't insert to have the information in the output if it's possible

Comment: Like output :  guidTable2 doesn't exist or something like that

Comment: LEFT JOIN combined with IS NOT NULL?!? Why not simply a regular INNER JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh you're right - an INNER JOIN would be equivalent here and a bit simpler. So unless the author specifically wanted the ability to also get non-matching rows, an INNER JOIN would suffice!